# Looking for a word to replace "separatableness"

Tags: word-request

Is there a word to refer to the quality of an object (or person) to distinguish other distinct objects?

Comment: What's wrong with the noun **distinctness**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of the words [**recognizability**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recognizability), [**distinguishability**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinguishability) and [**discernibility**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discernibility)?

Comment: Distinguishability sounds good. Anything fancier?

Comment: **Discernibility** sounds fancy enough.

Answer (score 3):

Well the grammatically correct version of 'separatableness' would be 'separability'.

However I think 'uniqueness' or 'distinctiveness' fits what you're looking for better.

Comment: Distinctiveness works well here.

Comment: Wouldn't distinctiveness solely mean that the object in consideration is different from other objects?
I want to say that the object has the ability to distinguish between **other** objects.

Comment: Oh so you're saying you have object A, which has the ability to tell the difference between objects B and C. You want to describe that ability of A?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with unique, or uniqueness

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.